# How can I get h2-header and manipulate with its value?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have this code:
.html:

```
<div *ngIf="isNotificationDisplayed" class="notification">
  <h2 align="center" class="set-margin" id="notification">Node was...!</h2>
  <h3 align="center">Press any key to hide it</h3>
</div>
```

and .ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-notifications',
  templateUrl: './notifications.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notifications.component.css']
})
export class NotificationsComponent implements OnInit {

  isNotificationDisplayed: boolean = false;
  notification: any = document.getElementById("notification");

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyDownKeyboardEvent(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (e) {
      this.isNotificationDisplayed = false;
    }
  }

  isCreated(name: string) {
    this.notification.value = `Node ${name} was created!`;
    this.isNotificationDisplayed = true;
  }

  isUpdated(name: string) {
    this.notification.value = `Node ${name} was updated!`;
    this.isNotificationDisplayed = true;
  }

  isDeleted(name: string) {
    this.notification.value = `Node ${name} was deleted!`;
    this.isNotificationDisplayed = true;
  }
}
```

But every time I try to get h2-header, notification = null.
And I don't know if it's possible to change h2 value in the same way as it's possible with Input.

Comment: In order to get the reference to the underlying HTML node, you should use `@ViewChild` decorator instead of using plain JS way of doing it. You can check official documentation for it: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Comment: Denis, can you please elaborate more by providing an example?

Comment: @Chaka15 , Yes, I'm going to do this. I just can't get html-element h2.

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar , when I try to get h2 in constructor, in some method or in ngOnInit, I get null. But if I try to get h2 in HostListener, I get it, but with the condition that it displays on my web-page.

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar , I dunno why but it seems like searching by id doesn't work or.. I dunno

Comment: Is it possible, that as long as `isNotificationDisplayed` is `false`, nothing inside `.notification` is rendered until `isNotificationDisplayed` changes to `false`?

Comment: @Denis, please try `console.log(...)` in `ngAfterViewInit` lifecylce method after you use `@ViewChild` to get the `h2`. Also `isNotificationDisplayed` must be `true`/truthy in order for `h2` not to be `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `innerHTML`. As mentioned on MDN

> The Element property innerHTML gets or sets the HTML or XML markup
> contained within the element.

[Read more and see examples here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Comment: Thank you) I'm sorry for question: don't you know by chance what cause can be that I can't get h2 in code? Every time I try to get it, notification = null.

Comment: In this case, `innerHTML` would be "too much" since this would result in a [reflow action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Reflow) by the browser because it expects HTML to parse when there is only text.

Answer (score 0):

`#notification` is not a form input. Form input values can be changed by modifying `value` attribute. But that doesn't work for other DOM elements. To achieve this, you have to use one of: `innerHTML`, `innerText`, or `textContent`. Use of the latter two is advised.

```js
isCreated(name: string) {
    this.notification.textContent = `Node ${name} was created!`;
    this.isNotificationDisplayed = true;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you) I'm sorry for question: don't you know by chance what cause can be that I can't get h2 in code? Every time I try to get it, notification = null.

Comment: @Denis When you `console.log(document.getElementById("notification"))` inside the `isCreated()` method, is it still `null`?